# Identify the white 4 pin part of this board

Tags: pcb

My touch screen monitors USB 2.0 Type B port is damaged. I tried to find a replacement but I don't know how to find one. So now I'm trying to construct one.

I've found a few boards that have the USB 2.0 port on a board. They don't however have the four pin white connector that the original cable plugs into.

[image]

[image]

What is that four pin connector called?

Also, what would this kind of pcb be called?

Comment: That board will have been designed and fabricated by the monitor manufacturer. You won't find a spare. You should have more chance of success looking for the USB socket and replace it instead.

Comment: JST connector. 2mm pitch probably.

Comment: Typical JST connector. As common as dirt.